# Hypothesis Testing of Vitamin Pill Potency

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

The supplier of a particular brand of vitamin pills claims that the average potency of these pills after a certain exposure to heat and humidity is at least $65$. The distributor who wishes to buy these pills is interested in testing the supplier's claim. The distributor considers it a more serious mistake to buy a batch of pills with a mean retention of vitamin potency that is less than $65$ than to reject a batch with a higher mean. It is given that $\sigma$ = $6$ with a sample size of n = $9$.

(a) Formulate the hypotheses about the mean potency of a batch of pills $\mu$ and determine the rejection region of the test with $\alpha$ = $.05.$

(b) If $\mu$ = $67$ what is the probability of a type II error?

(c) Compute the power of the test at a few values of $\mu$ that range between $63$ and $70$ and plot the power curve.

**Attemped Solution:**

(a) I'm most concerned that I'm mixing up $H_0$ and $H_1$. I'm having trouble distinguishing them from the question, but this is my guess.

$H_0$: $\mu < 65$

$H_1$: $\mu \geq 65$

$t_{8,.05}$ = $1.8595$

$\Rightarrow$ $65 + 1.8595(6)$ = $76.157$ so reject when $\mu_0$ > $76.157$

(b) P(Type II error) = P($\mu$ < $65$ | $\mu$ = $67$)

$\frac{65-67}{6\over\sqrt9}$ = $-1$ $\Rightarrow$ P(Type II error) = $.173$

(c)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without answering everything, I'll try to get you started on the right track.

Your null hypothesis $H_0: \mu < 65,$ cannot be right.
First, it is formally incorrect for *any* null hypothesis because
a null hypothesis must always contain an equal sign, whether
in the form $=, \le,$ or $\ge.$

Second, Because $\sigma = 6$ is known, you should be doing a z-test
instead of a t-test. (That is important, because finding Type II
error probabilities for a t-test is probably beyond what you're 
studying in this course.)

You are wondering whether the *direction* of your null hypothesis
is correct. To help with that, you might read [*this page*](http://www.weibull.com/hotwire/issue88/relbasics88.htm) where
$\alpha$ and 'Type I and II errors' are explained in terms
of 'Producer's Risk` and 'Consumer's Risk'.

Suppose we frame $H_0$ and $H_1$ so that rejecting the null
hypothesis corresponds to rejecting the lot. Then we want
$H_0: \mu \ge 65$ and $H_1: \mu < 65.$

Then the test statistic is

$$Z = \frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} = \frac{\bar X - 65}{2},$$
where $\bar X$ is the mean potency of $n = 9$ randomly chosen pills.
Under $H_0$ (meaning 'assuming the null hypothesis to be true') you
have $Z \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1)$ and you reject $H_0$ at level
$\alpha = 0.05$ if $Z < - 1.645,$ chosen because $P(Z < - 1.645) = 0.05.$ 
In terms of $\bar X,$ you reject $H_0$ if $\bar X < 61.71.$

Notice that if $\bar X = 64.5,$ just a little below 65, we don't reject
$H_0$ because a slight deficiency in the sample of 9 might be due
to chance. But if $\bar X$ is *significantly* below 65, we do reject $H_0.$

If the true potency is $65,$ you would reject $H_0,$ and the lot of pills, with probability 5%.
(That would be unfavorable to the 'producers' because they are losing
a sale.)

Now the distributor may worry if a lot of pills in which $\bar X$ is 
a little under 65 may still be of undesirably low potency. That is
where Type II error comes in. Type II error is $P(\text{Accept}|\text{Low potency}).$ But there are *many ways* for potency to be low. 
So $P(\text{Type II Err}|\mu) = \beta(\mu)$ is a not a single value,
but a *function* of $\mu.$ This corresponds to the distributor's or
'consumer's' risk, because (for $\mu <65$) it involves accepting a batch of pills
that are below the required potency.

Also 
$$\text{Power}(\mu) = \gamma(\mu) = 1 - \beta(\mu) = P(\text{Reject}|\mu)
= P(\bar X < 61.71|\mu).$$

I will show you what I get for a power curve for some values of $\mu$
between 55 and 70. Based on what you show or your work, I think you
should be able to do the computations to make a similar curve on your own.
The value at $\mu=65$ shows the significance level 0.05.
(Graph made using R statistical software.)

[image]

It seems to me that $n=9$ may be too few sample pills to give a good
power for batches that are just a little below 65 in potency. The *dotted red*
curve on a similar plot made using Minitab, shows better performance
for $n = 16.$ (The horizontal axis shows *differences* from $\mu=65;$
the solid blue curve is essentially the same as mine.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for another well explained answer. The sample size of 9 and being given $\sigma$ threw me off.

Comment: Thanks, Some typos fixed. Repairs don't change rejection region or power curve.

Comment: If a following question gives me 9 data values and asks to apply the test with these, should I use the calculated s instead of $\sigma$? Thus using a test statistic of 1.8595?

Comment: I'd guess your just supposed to find $\bar X$ and still use $\sigma$ as given, unless there clues to the contrary.